# App crashes in "voice over" when UIContextualAction has an empty title - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, ios11, voiceover

I have the following code in my project,

```
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let emailAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                         title: "",
                                         handler: { (_, _, success: (Bool) -> Void) in
        // Some code
        success(true)
    })
    emailAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "envelope")

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                          title: "",
                                          handler: { (_, _, success: (Bool) -> Void) in
        // Some code
        success(true)
    })
    deleteAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trash")

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [emailAction, deleteAction])
}
```

It crashes when I switch on voice over. Find below for the error I get,

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableTextAccessibilityElement _accessibilityCustomActionNamesAndIdentifiers], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AccessibilityFrameworks/AccessibilityFrameworks-2396.1.4/Source/UIAccessibility/NSObjectAccessibility.m:3249

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAccessibilityCustomAction must have a name.'

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did and I got it working:

I did recreate the project but this time I was using Storyboards (I wasn't the last time) and I imported from Cocoapods the [SwipeCellKit Library](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) and I followed their documentation and VoiceOver was working perfectly fine with deleting a cell from them indexPath.row with no problem.